# Image Not Displaying On Web Page

Tags: html, image

I am probably missing the blindingly obvious but I can't figure out why an image is not displaying on my web site.  Here is the HTML:

```
<p>Above the image</p>
<img src="/Trends/TDBFGLogo5.gif" alt="" />
<p>Below the image</p>
```

My code is executing in the directory D:\WebApp which contains a folder called Trends that has all of my images.  I have even tried the absolute path D:/WebApp/Trends/TDBFGLogo5.gif but all I see is:

```
Above the image

Below the image
```

I have no CSS that affects the img tag and this tag is in the body of the HTML.

Any advice is appreciated.

Regards.

Comment: Where is the image relative to where html code is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<p>Above the image</p>
<img src="Trends/TDBFGLogo5.gif" alt="" />
<p>Below the image</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this

```
<p>Above the image</p>
<img src="./Trends/TDBFGLogo5.gif" alt="" />
<p>Below the image</p>
```